# Golang certificate validation

Tags: ssl, go, cryptography, x509

I'm using Go to perform HTTPS requests with a custom root CA. The root CA is the only certificate I have on my side.

My code looks like this:

```golang
// performRequest sets up the HTTPS Client we'll use for communication and handle the actual requesting to the external
// end point. It is used by the auth and collect adapters who set their response data up first.
func performRequest(rawData []byte, soapHeader string) (*http.Response, error) {
  conf := config.GetConfig()

  // Set up the certificate handler and the HTTP client.
  certPool := x509.NewCertPool()
  certPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(certificate)
  client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
      TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            certPool,
        InsecureSkipVerify: false,
      },
    },
  }

  req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, baseURL, bytes.NewBuffer(rawData))
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  // Sets the SOAPAction and Content-Type headers to the request.
  req.Header.Set("SOAPAction", soapHeader)
  req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8")

  // Send request as our custom client, return response
  return client.Do(req)
}
```

The error I get back is this:

```
2017/12/09 21:06:13 Post https://secure.site: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match secure.site
```

I've been unable to find out exactly what the cause is of this. When checking the SANs of the CA cert, I don't have `secure.site` in there (no names at all, as the error states), but I can't see how I've done this wrong.

What should I do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. add the CA certificate on the server side as well, the CA needs to be known by all parties.
2. generate and use a server certificate (with the hostname in the certificate) on the server. The server cert needs to be signed by the CA.

You can find an example of this at [here](https://github.com/jcbsmpsn/golang-https-example) (first google example)

Edit: to clarify, the error is due to the fact that you are trying to connect securely to a remote host. By default, the go client will look for a valid certificate returned by the server.

Valid means (among other things):

1. it is signed by a known CA
2. it contains the ip/dns of the server (the one you passed to `http.NewRequest`) in the `CommonName` or `Subject Alternative Name: DNS/IP` fields.

**final edit**:

The server certificate contained the correct `Common Name` set to the server hostname, but it also contained a `Subject Alternative Name` set to an email address.

As mentioned in https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/security-dev/IGT2fLJrAeo, Go now ignores the `Common Name` if is a SAN is found.

Comment: The certificate is already in production in another system I'm porting. Also, running `wget https://secure.site --ca-certificate=/the/certificate` works. There must be something wrong in my implementation.

Comment: Can you dump the contents of the server cert using: `$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect secure.site:443`, we're looking for the `Server certificate: subject` section.

Comment: `Server certificate
subject=/C=SE/O=Company Inc./OU=Server1024/serialNumber=165563372191/CN=secure.site
issuer=/C=SE/O=Issues Inc./CN=Issuer Inc. EID CA v2`

Comment: That is odd. I'm pretty sure the certificate validity check comes before the host check so your CA should be fine. Just to make sure, can you add `--verify_hostname secure.site` to the openssl command? It should finish with `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

Comment: I get all the output again... should I remove any other parameters? Also, I'm curious as of whether it's related to this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22922

Comment: That might be it. One last try: `openssl s_client -connect secure.site:443 | openssl x509 -noout -text`. That dumps the entire certificate. Look for `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name`. If the field is there but does not contain `secure.site`, that's your problem.

Comment: Yup, you got it!

`X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: email:secure@company.com`

If you want to, make an answer about that bug, stating that Go have actively decided to ignore CNs if there are SANs and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Sure, I'll just edit my previous answer. It's all on you for finding the issue though, glad I learned something.

Comment: "...Go now ignores the Common Name if is a SAN is found..." According to RFC 2818 that is a bug, pure and simple.